# jQuery character count if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement, jquery-plugins

I have the following character count plugin:if there is more than 9 characters the alert class is added to change the color to red.
What I want is when I say '**if number of character is more than 9**', to replace the number 9 with a var.

```
if(number_of_characters >= 9) {
```

So this value can always be adjusted from the plugin options, instead of changing this value inside the jQuery plugin.

How should I do this?

[My working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/43gxup1s/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqnLcpdb/).

What I did was add a new option - `number_of_characters` (you can name it w/e you want):

```
$(textarea).CountCharacters({
    Start_Count: 0,
    Amount_Result: "counter",
    Alert_Class: "alert-counter",
    Amount_Limit: 19,
    number_of_characters: 5
});
```

Then, instead of hardcoding the value, I referred to the new option:

```
if(number_of_characters >= options.number_of_characters) {
    $("#"+options.Amount_Result).addClass(options.Alert_Class);
}
```

I also set a new default option:

```
var defaults = {
  Start_Count: 0,
  Amount_Result: false,
  Alert_Class: false,
  number_of_characters: 9
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new property to the `defaults` object, and read from that. This can then be overridden as needed for each instance. Try this:

```
// declaration:
var defaults = {
    Start_Count: 0,
    Amount_Result: false,
    Alert_Class: false,
    maximumCharacters: 9
}

// usage:
 if (number_of_characters >= options.maximumCharacters) {
    $("#" + options.Amount_Result).addClass(options.Alert_Class);
} else {
    $("#" + options.Amount_Result).removeClass(options.Alert_Class);
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/43gxup1s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use the option Amount_Limit

```
$(textarea).CountCharacters({
    Start_Count: 0,
    Amount_Result: "counter",
    Alert_Class: "alert-counter",
    Amount_Limit: 9
});

if(number_of_characters >= options.Amount_Limit)
```